# Creating a PCL NET 4.0 gives me an error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I am using VS 2015 Pro. If I create a new project Class Library (portable) Targeting:
NET Framework 4.0
Windows 8

all works fine.

BUT when I add to the targeting:
**Windows Phone 8.1**

the following two errors appear:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
>   being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference 
>   "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "x86".
>   This mismatch may cause runtime failures.

And the Linq not found:

> The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(PS. I am sure that everything worked fine till I let Visual Studio 2015 update some Extensions)

**NOTE** If I target x86 the first error goes away, but the second remains.

1) What now is happening with the Windows Phone 8 and
where Visual Studio is loading the Windows Phone 8 assemblies?

2) How can I restore the Windows Phone 8 assemblies?
[image]

**EDIT**

[image: Project references]

**EDIT2**

**IMPORTANT 
If I change the targeting, and choose NET 4.0.3 the project compiles fine!**

[image: project compiles with Phone 8.1 and NET 4.0.3]

**EDIT3 IMPORTANT**
I have found that it has something to do with the Framework Profiles for NET portable, that are stored at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable

(link [framework profiles](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html)

Using Package Manager Console for my project:
PM> $p.Properties.Item("TargetFrameworkMoniker").Value
.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile328

In the folder for Profile328 I have noted that there aren't inside the .dlls
but only the .xml files... What happened?! How to restore?!

Comment: for Q1 . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113532/how-do-i-fix-the-visual-studio-compile-error-mismatch-between-processor-archit

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

When you have the portable class library, you have this situation:
In the .NET assembly there is all library if you want.

Try to delete project and create new portable class library

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: In my project the References tab is empty... (it suggest to use Object browser ... but for what?) Please see my edit

Comment: I have tried to maually add the Linq reference from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0
but nothing changes

Comment: No... I have been busy, sorry... 
The problem is that I have created a new project (for investingating this issue). And the problem appear when I choose NET 4.0 and Phone 8.1

Comment: If I target NET 4.0.3 the project compiles fine!
(But for backward compatibility reason I can't change the targeting)
Where is VS2015 picking up the NET 4.0 and Phone 8.1 references...???

Comment: I use VS 2013 PRO, when I create the PortableClassLibrary I can choose the framework version. If i choose 4.0 my project run.